# Ionic/Angular: How to bind an input decorator to a form control value?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-formbuilder, angular-decorator

In my app I have a component (search page) that has a sub-component (search field) which has an input field. On another pages I do a router navigation to that component with query parameters: `search?q=hello`. The search page holds the logic to get the query param and pass it to the search field with `<app-search [query]="paramQuery"></app-search>`. When I'm directly loading the search page the search field correctly gets that `paramQuery` value but when the search component and therefore the search field has already been loaded and I'm navigating back to the search page, it still holds the old value.

**Code:**

https://github.com/muuvmuuv/issue-ionic-decorators-injection

1. Install `npm i`
2. Run `npm start`
3. Go to `/tabs/tab1`
4. Type something in the form
5. Press enter → redirects to `/tabs/tab2?q=XXX`
6. Go back to `/tabs/tab1` through tab bar or link
7. Type something different in the form
8. Press enter → redirects to `/tabs/tab2?q=XXX`
9. Form value not updated!